# My html pages are not reading my style.css sheet and classes

Tags: html, css

I made some changes to my website including the style.css and reponsive.css but now, my pages aren't reading the style.css at all but its reading everything else and I can't figure out why.

Everything seems to be correctly linked: but for some reason certain styles in my style.css aren't being applied to my website.

I have tried to inspect the site (F12) and I see that its not picking up the styles.

I have tried the !important tag, still nothing.

The style sheet is correctly linking but for some reason its not reading the classes.

This is the link on my site to the style.css

`<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

for example: I have this section on my site:

```css
.main_test {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.test_item {
  padding: 40px;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.test_item:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.test_item:hover .item_img i {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #de2c27;
}

.main_test .item_img {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.main_test .item_text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
}

.item_img {
  position: relative;
}

.item_img i {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: -13%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<section id="test" class="test bg-grey roomy-60 fix">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="main_test fix">

        <div class="col-md-12">

          <div class="test_item fix">
            <div class="item_img">
              <img class="img-circle" img alt="URS-Customer-reference" src="assets/images/Customer-Ref-MensShoe.jpg">
              <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="item_text">
              <h5><strong>TEXT</strong></h5>
              <h6>TEXT2</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

But its not reading it.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache? So that it isn't working with an earlier version of the stylesheet.

Comment: maybe you sould use .main_test.fix? [link](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/#article-header-id-2)

Comment: @GiovanniCappelletti Why? That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: It may be recognized as a double class, but it should work anyway

Comment: As you have used a relative path - is the file in the correct place relative to the url serving the page?  If not, try using an absolute path: `/assets/css/style.css`  If that doesn't work try looking at your network tab in developer tools to see if it throws a 404, if it doesn't you may want to try a hard refresh

Comment: youre using bootstrap?

Comment: @godfather yes I am using Bootstrap

Comment: the problem isnt solved yet?

Comment: @godfather unfortunately not, im thinking whether i should just start over, something is possibly clashing here.

Comment: i was wondering if its the bootstrap  cdn link problem

Comment: if you have multiple css file then you try to change the position of css file.

Comment: @godfather please give more detail on this cdn link problem? And what can I do to rectify?

Comment: you have css links in the head ?

Comment: @VISHALSINGH i will try that

Comment: do you have the bootstrap css style link in <head>?

Comment: just to check if this is the problem  if you dont have this css link try to add it in head : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: @godfather yes i do